# showing that collections are proper classes without replacement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering about a simple proof that the collection of all sets of a given order type, and the collection of all sets of a given cardinality, are proper classes.  Specifically, I'd like a simple proof of this claim which does not use Replacement.  Presumably there is an argument stemming from Russell's Paradox exploiting the Union Axiom, but it would be helpful to me if one could outline it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which axioms will you be using?

Comment: ZF - Replacement is fine (though presumably Foundation won't be needed).

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right: Union is the way to go. The key observation is that $\{x: x=x\}$ is never a set (since then Russell's Paradox kicks in via Separation), so we just need to show how to get that set from any of the classes we're considering.

Let's first show that the class of singletons is not a set. This is easy: if $W=\{\{x\}: x=x\}$, then $\bigcup W=\{x: x=x\}$ giving us Russell's paradox.

This immediately extends to classes of the form "all sets of cardinality $\kappa$". With a bit of thought, it also extends to structures (linear orders, groups, . . .)! What's a structure? Well, it's an ordered pair $(x, y)$ where $x$ is the domain and $y$ is the "structure" (e.g. a binary relation on $x$, or . . .). The point is that if $A$ is a set of ordered pairs, then $\bigcup\bigcup . . .\bigcup A$ contains every set which is the left coordinate of some element of $A$ (where the exact number of unions you need depends on which definition of ordered pair you use); the point is that taking unions "removes one set of curly braces". For instance, in the Kuratowski ordered pair $$(a, b):=\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\},$$ we have $$a\in\{a\}\in (a, b),$$ so if $(a, b)\in A$ we have $a\in\bigcup\bigcup A$. Now since e.g. every set is the domain of a linear order (see below), the class of linear orders is not a set.

Well, hey! Actually I said something nontrivial: the statement "Every set can be linearly ordered" is **not** obviously true in ZF! In fact, it *isn't* true in ZF: there are, consistently, non-linearly-orderable sets! So maybe this is less obvious than it seems?

Well, okay fine, here's what we do: every set${}$**'s singleton** is the domain of a linear order. So we just throw one more "$\bigcup$" onto the pile.

Comment: Thanks, Noah!  This is what I was thinking.  What I wondered is how to show rigorously that every set would appear in the ⋃⋃...⋃A⋃⋃...⋃A, where A is a collection of all sets of a given order-type or cardinality.  This is "obvious".  But how would you show it rigorously?  Thanks again!

Comment: @davidp Let's take cardinality. I gave the $n=1$ case, but maybe that looked slippery? Let's look at $n=2$. Then every set $x$ is an element of a two-element set, namely $\{x, \{x\}\}$. So if $A$ is the set of all two-element sets, then $x$ is an element of an element of $A$ - this means $x\in\bigcup A$ (this is a good exercise). For order-types, we have to fix a notion of ordered pair (as I say in my post), but then the argument is again quite simple.

Comment: Oh, I see -- you're suggesting that in both cases we can actually just use a single set to build up a member of the cardinality class or order-type -- e.g., making an omega-sequence of x, {x}, {x, {x}}, etc. or some such?

Comment: @davidp Basically, yes. Or, you can take a fixed set of the appropriate cardinality/ordertype/whatever, and alter one of its elements appropriately (e.g. $1\le 2\le \{x\}\le 4\le 5\le . . .$).

Comment: That's very helpful.  Thanks again!